# How to make input value appear in another input in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When i press Edit button the value of task shoukld apper in edit input block.
I made this code but it only appear the index of current line:(

```
 <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask($index)">Delete</button>
                     <!--  $index-->
                 </td>
                <td>{{task.taskName}}</td>
             <td>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="statusCheck"> </td>
             <td style="{{setStyleToTd(statusCheck)}}">{{statusChecker(statusCheck)}}</td>
             <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editTask($index)">Edit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
  $scope.editTask = function (taskToDelete) {
    $scope.editTaskInput = taskToDelete;
}
```

[image: task manager]

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: its dangerous to use $index if you are using filter to search the array. $index  does not return correct index with filter , better to find the actual index inside  `deleteTask(task)` using indexOf()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution for your side.

You can resolve it by using `ng-click="editTask(task.taskName)"` instead of `ng-click="editTask($index)"`.

### Solution from My side:

You need update the task name. So you should pass `task`  object instead of `$index` in your `edittask()` click event. then you can get the current selected `taskname` from the `task` object also you can update.

try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask($index)">Delete</button>
                     <!--  $index-->
                 </td>
                <td>{{task.taskName}}</td>
             <td>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="statusCheck"> </td>
             <td style="{{setStyleToTd(statusCheck)}}">{{statusChecker(statusCheck)}}</td>
             <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editTask(task)">Edit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
  $scope.editTask = function (taskToEdit) {
    $scope.editTaskInput = taskToEdit.taskName;
}
```

Comment: @Niladri Your correct. but it's unrelated  comment for this question.

Comment: @Niladri . Then you should post your comment under his question. not my answer buddy. :)